# SAssetView Slate Compile Errors

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit, unreal-umg

After trying to add a `SAssetView` slate widget to my code, I run into some compile errors.

The picture here is from the class that is extending `SCoumpoundWidget`, and the second picture is of the compile errors.

**Code Snippet:**

[image: code snippet]

**Compile Error:**

[image: compile error]

Comment: To make it easier for people to help you please include the text of the code and error in your post (not as an image). And make sure to use stack overflows markdown formatting to keep it readable.

Comment: Does the SAsestView compile without the FStorageAssetViewWidget implementation ? Did you declare the SAssetView virtual events in the header and implemented them ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missing some symbols during the linking part of the compilation. Compiler seems to be looking for implementations of virtual methods from parent.
Did you follow the wiki about [Slate](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Slate,_Hello), and mostly did you include the `Slate` and `SlateCore` module inside your build.cs ?
`PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Slate", "SlateCore" });`

`SCompoundWidget` is inside the SlateCore module, and if you didn't include it, compiler will not be able to find symbols for Slate classes.

Btw : it could be easier if you gave us direct code (as mpkorstanje commented), and more than your `Construct` method. The class declaration could help to find the error.

Hope it helped

Comment: Sadly yes, More then that, Its not my only SCompoundWidget, The first one is working great (Well, As much as it can i suppose)